# Redirect after WP login with wp-login hook

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I added an action hook based on 'wp_login' which get an ACF value defined in the user who just logged in, connect an API which respond with a URL and I need to redirect the user to this given URL.

All the above function works fine BUT once I tried to do the redirect - at the front end I receive error "Error occurred: parsererror" or "Error occurred: error".

I tried to do the redirect with:

1. wp_redirect
2. header("Location: XXX)
3. add_filter('login_redirect', 'function xx')
4. add_filter( 'login_url', 'function xx')

All end up with the same errors.

once I remove the redirect line, it all works fine so It have to be an issue with the redirect.
I tried to redirect to an external page (https://www.google.com/) and to the site home page and end up with the same errors...

Any thought ?

Here is the code:

```
function after_login_send_to_global1simapi ( $user_login, $user ) {
if (is_page ( 35662 )) {
    $cs = get_field('client_secret', 'user_' . $user->ID);
    if ($cs == '') { //if CS empty redirect user to XX page.
        add_filter('login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect');
    } else {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://global1simapi.roamhostapi.com/api/services/app/WiFly/WiflySigninWoocommerce?ClientSecret=' . $cs,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        //save cookie with CS
        setcookie ('CS', $cs);

        $user_data = (array) json_decode ($response);
        $url = $user_data['result'];  //URL to redirect
        
        //it all works up to here - once I add the following 2 lines. 
        //the login failed with the above mentioned errors.
        //but although it display those error, the user does logged in
        //if I refresh the page, the user is logged in.

        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }

}
```

}
add_action('wp_login', 'after_login_send_to_global1simapi', 10, 2);

Comment: Try to use the ob_start like
 ob_start();
    wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
 ob_clean();

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I tried that, but same result.

Comment: can you post your login code?